# Actionscript 3.0 Tween Question

Tags: actionscript-3, tween

I am currently working on a website for a construction company and I am trying to build a very simple flash intro. I have two images in the falsh intro: a tractor and a picture of clouds in the background.

I am trying to have the clouds appear to float by in the background. It is a very wide image that I am trying to loop through very slowly. It looks pretty cool :) IMO.

For tweening, I have always used TweenLite. The problem I am having is that while the image is moving, it 'blips' and looks pretty choppy. I have adjusted fps and about every other thing I can think of. The only thing that fixes it is when I use Hardware Acceleration (Level 2 - GPU). But this creates all sorts of problems for the HTML page.

My Question Is:
I am just a terrible coder, or would I be better off using Tweener (or something of the sort) or using the native tween engine in flash cs4? Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these:

If the image is in your Library, make sure "Allow smoothing" is checked in your Bitmap Properties (select the image in the Library and go to "Properties" in the Library menu).

Or, if you are loading the bitmap dynamically and using the BitmapData class, make sure you've set the "smoothing" property to "true" on your BitmapData.

Comment: do you not mean cacheAsBitmap? I thought smoothing was to blur the image for when pixelation occurs due to scaling?

Comment: thanks Reuben, that fixed my problem. I can't believe that it was just a checkbox. AHHHGGG.

Comment: @Allan - smoothing allows sub-pixel rendering of bitmaps - useful for scaling, but also for tweening if the x or y value of the bitmap parent is not an integer.